# UICollectionViewCell for AppleTV does not display contents in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, xcode7, uicollectionviewcell, apple-tv

When trying to build up a UICollectionViewCell for an AppleTV app, its contents are not displayed, making it more difficult to good design. Does anyone know whether this is a bug or something I'm doing wrong?

The contents do appear when moving, below are 2 screenshots, one of the normal state, and one of the state of moving an element.

I'm using Xcode version 7.1.1 (7B1005)

[image: normal state]

[image: moving an element]

Answer (score 1):

I tried and it looks like the cell will only be rendered, if you embed it in a collection view which is embedded in the main view. Additionally you have to add some auto layout constraints:

[image]